# Java Card Reader With Netbeans

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, smartcard, javacard, reader

I have Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0     at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4454)

[image]

what should i do ? how to know smart card has connected ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the post to include the text of the code in the post. Do not use images as members may want to run your code to see what is wrong. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your smart card reader is a PCSC reader / in CCID mode; this is the default type of smart card reader that the SmartCardIO implementation looks for. This question is probably best asked at an Ubuntu related site, mentioning the terms above. Don't forget to mention the type of reader, if there is a card in / on it, the Ubuntu version etc., i.e. add lots of details.

Comment: thank you Elletlar and Maarten for the answer

Comment: Did you use a PC/SC reader and get it working?